# Sort a javascript array into nested arrays based on values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mapping

I have an array of file names like so:

```
var filesArray = [
    "120.png",
    "120s.png",
    "120t.jpg",
    "169.png",
    "169r.jpg",
    "169s.jpg",
    "169t.jpg",
    "170.png",
    "170r.jpg",
    "170s.jpg",
    "170t.jpg",
]
```

Using javascript (es5 or 6 or 7 does not matter since I am using babel) I would like to sort it into a nested array like so:

```
[
    [
        "120.png",
        "120s.png",
        "120t.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "170.png",
        "170r.jpg",
        "170s.jpg",
        "170t.jpg"
    ]
]
```

I know that in order to find the same base names I have to run regex and I am already using `filesArray[i].slice(0, -4).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '') )`

What I don't know however is how to run `array.sort` or `array.map` to get the final neste array.

By the way, it's long list of file names, and I would prefer the fastest most efficient way to do so without mutating the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for grouping the items.

```js
var filesArray = ["120.png", "120s.png", "120t.jpg", "169.png", "169r.jpg", "169s.jpg", "169t.jpg", "170.png", "170r.jpg", "170s.jpg", "170t.jpg"],
    grouped = [];

filesArray.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.slice(0, -4).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''),
        array = this.get(key);

    if (!array) {
        array = [];
        this.set(key, array);
        grouped.push(array);
    }
    array.push(a);
}, new Map);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you like my version? And can i use your css on my anwer :)?

Comment: yes, you can use the css. your answer needs an additional loop for the result.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var filesArray = ["120.png", "120s.png", "120t.jpg", "169.png", "169r.jpg", "169s.jpg", "169t.jpg", "170.png", "170r.jpg", "170s.jpg", "170t.jpg"];
var result = [];
var obj = filesArray.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array) {
  var rawName = curr.match(/[0-9]/g);
  if (rawName.length) {
    var name = rawName.join('');
    if (prev[name]) {
      prev[name].push(curr);
    } else {
      prev[name] = [curr];
    }
  }
  return prev
}, {});

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  result.push(obj[key]);
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
.as-console-row,
.as-console-row-code {
  background-color: #fff!important;
}
```